# Erro ao tentar conectar sql server 2014 com o hibernate-core 5.2.7 Final

Tags: hibernate, java-8, sql-server-2014

Estou aprendendo java com hibernate. Estou utilizando o maven para gerenciar o projeto. Me ocorre o seguinte erro INFO: **HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found** como abaixo na imagem (clicar na imagem para ela ficar maior).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O stack trace do erro é esse

```
aqui
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.cloud.util.HibernateUtil.criarFabricaDeSessoes(HibernateUtil.java:26)
at com.cloud.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
at com.cloud.util.HibernateUtilTest.conectar(HibernateUtilTest.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
```

Estou usando a versao do Hibernate Core 5.2.7.Final
Meu arquivo hibernate.cfg.xml é este abaixo:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=Cloud</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">******</property>        
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Abaixo o meu arquivo pow.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cloud</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SQLServer connector -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
                <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.3.jre8-preview</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate 5.2.7 Final -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build> 
        <!-- nome do projeto empacotado (nome do .war) -->
        <finalName>Cloud</finalName>        
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Essa é a minha classe HibernateUtil.java

```
package com.cloud.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory fabricaDeSessoes = criarFabricaDeSessoes();

    public static SessionFactory getFabricaDeSessoes() {
        return fabricaDeSessoes;
    }

    private static SessionFactory criarFabricaDeSessoes() {
        try {
            Configuration configuracao = new Configuration().configure();

            ServiceRegistry registro = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuracao.getProperties()).build();

            SessionFactory fabrica = configuracao.buildSessionFactory(registro);

            return fabrica;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("A fábrica de sessões não pode ser criada." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Alguém que manja saberia me falar o que pode ser? Tentei umas mil coisas e não entendo o que há de errado. 
Valeu, aguardo!

Comment: Onde você colocou o arquivo `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: Oi Felipe, obrigado por responder. Eu coloquei na pasta src\main\resourses.

Comment: Edite sua resposta e coloque a stack trace da exceção, por favor.

Comment: Coloquei o stack trace como pediu.

Comment: Tem certeza que é só isso que aparece na stacktrace? Deveria aparecer mais algo indicando qual é o erro, se o hibernate não consegue se conectar ao banco, se ele não conseguiu se autenticar, etc. As únicas coisas que posso te sugerir são: tentar utilizar uma versão do driver que não esteja marcada como preview, mudar o `hibernate.dialect` para um mais recente como o `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect` e verificar se o nome da instância, o nome do banco de dados, a senha e o usuário estão corretos.